# Sum attributes model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to calculate `total_price` in `medic_record`

```
total_price = med_show + lab_price + total_room
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "medic_records", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "lab_price"
    t.decimal  "med_show"
    t.decimal  "total_price"
    t.decimal  "total_room"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
  end
```

**My method in medic_record model**

```
before_save :save_total

def save_total
  self.update_all(total_price: self.med_show + self.lab_price + self.total_room)
end
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError (nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal):
>   app/models/medic_record.rb:31:in '+'
>   app/models/medic_record.rb:31:in 'save_total'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer. I would advise against introducing columns like `total_price` in your DB though.

Comment: Ups sorry. I move my answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Oh man, i have try this method and fix !!

```
def save_total
  self.total_price = self.med_show.to_s.to_d + self.lab_price.to_s.to_d + self.total_room.to_s.to_d
end
```

Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert to float each field to make the sum:

```
def save_total
  total_price=med_show.to_f+lab_price.to_f+total_room.to_f
end
```

Eventhough, I can't understand why  `update_all(`, because this method in the model indentifies 1 record on database, `save_total` will be executed for each record of the table